# How to add a .o on a static library with Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, static

I have a .h and a .o that I need to add to a static library in Eclipse. I'm able to add it to an application with the Linker options, but for a static library, I haven't found where to add it in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G'day,

I know it sounds clunky, but you might have to come out of Eclipse and use ar directly. For example:

```
ar -rv my_lib.a new_obj.o
ranlib
```

Running ranlib is probably not required anymore with more recent implementations of ar but it's best to run it anyway to make sure that the table has been updated.

HTH